# All my bootstrap projects have their Javascript rejected on Internet Explorer (All Versions)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I've made a few projects in Bootstrap. I'm noticing that they are cross browser compatible with everything except Internet Explorer.

When I load my files on Internet Explorer, I get a box at the bottom of the page saying: "Internet Explorer has restricted this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls" there is a button marked 'Allow Content' which when pressed all my Javascript will work.

How can I stop it from blocking my scripts? This happens with any project I make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to IE security settings that prohibits the execution of JavaScript code (as well as ActiveX objects). This only applies when a page is run locally so this should not be a problem when running on a server.

If it bothers you, you have two options:

1. Launch Internet Explorer -> Navigate to Tools/Internet Options -> Click on the Advanced ta -> Scroll down to the Security section and Enable the option entitled “Allow active content to run in files on My Computer” -> Apply the change
2. Launch RegEdit and navigate to the following location and change the data on the value from 1 to 0. 
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN, iexplore.exe